# Navigating Phoenix's or Elixir's Codebase in Vim using cTags

Tags: macos, vim, elixir, phoenix-framework, exuberant-ctags

This is my setup:

```
Mac OS          10.12.1
ViM             8.0.52
Exuberant Ctags 5.8
```

My `.vimrc` has: `set tags=tags`

I generate the tags file using `ctags -R .` within the project root directory and it generated a file called `tags` in that same folder.

The ctags navigation within my own project files work just fine. But whenever I try to see the source code for the Phoenix Framework itself (or its dependencies) I get a

```
E426: Tag not found: Mix
```

How do I fix this and navigate Phoenix's source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I've somehow corrupted my project's installation.

After trying to fix the tags specific issue, I just decided to give up and move on. Trying to run `mix phoenix.server` I got:

```
Unchecked dependencies for environment test:
```

(...) list of all dependencies, including the final one:

```
* phoenix_ecto (Hex package)
  the dependency is not available, run "mix deps.get"
** (Mix) Can't continue due to errors on dependencies
```

I have no idea how this happened. So I ran `mix deps.get` again and also had to run `npm install` again. (Phoenix uses **brunch**)

After that, I ran `$ ctags -R .` on the project's root directory and everything is working fine: both the project and the ctags navigation, including Phoenix's and Elixir's source code.